# Confusion on memory address for NSString between view Controllers

Tags: ios, properties, automatic-ref-counting, viewcontroller, setter

In my child view controller, I have a property defined as:

`@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;`

In view controller A, the Parent, I have the following:

```
NSString *temp = currency.name; //This is because currency is a Core Data Managed Object.
                                //I wanted to make sure it wasn't a confounding factor.

childViewController.name = temp;

if(childViewController.name == temp)
  NSLog(@"I am surprised");
```

The problem is that `if` statement finds equivalency and the "I am surprised" is printed.  I thought that `==` should be checking if they're the same object, and that the use of `copy` in the property declaration should ensure the setter is making a copy.  I checked in the debugger and they are both pointing to the same string.  (Which I believe is immutable, which may be why this is happening?)

The same thing happens even if I write `childViewController.name = [temp copy];`, which I find shocking!

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Edit: I removed a bit here on worrying about a circular reference which I realized wasn't a concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an optimization.

For immutable objects, it's superfluous to create an actual copy, so `- copy` is often implemented as a simple retain, i. e.

```
- (id)copy
{
    [self retain];
    return self;
}
```

Try assigning a mutable object (e. g. `NSMutableString`) to the property, and you will get the "expected" behavior.

Comment: This is what makes learning the behavior of == so confusing when you start out with strings...

Comment: @ElTea I don't see the relation to either the "behavior of ==" or strings in general. This is an optimization related to immutability, that's all. `==` works just as it would work in any other case.

Comment: My point was that if you were starting out and make the `==` error on comparing strings, it might seem to work for a while because the strings will often be the same.  At any rate, you totally nailed it, making the temp string a `NSMutableString` forced two different addresses.  Thanks much.

Comment: @ElTea Oh well, yes. That's why one should take the use of `isEqual:` or `isEqualToString:` seriously :)